# Is it possible to get coverage information from a golang tool (i.e. not a test)?

Tags: go, testing, integration-testing, code-coverage

I have a go module for which I need an integration test to verify that most everything is covered.

With a unit test, I go do:

```
go test -cover
```

Which is great! (See [here](https://blog.golang.org/cover))

Since I need to run an integration test (i.e. Redis needs to be running), I have a tool and I start it with:

```
go run cmd/integration/test.go
```

and the `-cover` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Why don't you just run your integration test with `go test`?

Comment: @Crowman some tests require heavy external systems to be running before I can run some of my integration tests. It may be 10 different dockers, for example. So just `go test` would prevent the more basic unit tests to run to completion if it requires the full integration tests to also be able to run. Now Phles solution will most certainly resolve the issue very nicely.

Comment: You're using the wrong approach. Don't try to get test coverage from `go run`--instead, run your integration tests using `go test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is build tags.
Place the following at the top of your redis integration test above the package line:

```
// +build integration
```

Run:

```
go test -cover -tags=integration
```

to run integration tests with code coverage.

Further reading:
https://mickey.dev/posts/go-build-tags-testing/